# What does the subscribers array do in the HOC withUser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Just as the title says, I don't understand in this code what does the subscribers.

```
import React from "react";

const stateFromStore = sessionStorage.getItem('user');

let state = stateFromStore ? JSON.parse(stateFromStore) : null;

const subscribers = [];

const unsubscribe = subscriber => {
    const index = subscribers.findIndex(subscriber);
    index >= 0 && subscribers.splice(index, 1);
};
const subscribe = subscriber => {
    subscribers.push(subscriber);
    return () => unsubscribe(subscriber);
};

export const withUser = Component => {
    return class WithUser extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.unsubscribe = subscribe(this.forceUpdate.bind(this));
        }
        render() {
            const newProps = { ...this.props, user: state };
            return <Component {...newProps} />;
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.unsubscribe();
        }
    };
};
export const update = newState => {
    state = newState;
    sessionStorage.setItem('user', state ? JSON.stringify(state) : null);
    subscribers.forEach(subscriber => subscriber());
};
```

I get the part about sessionStorate but I don't understand the use of the subscribers array.

This is part of an example about how to use passport with react https://github.com/HackedByChinese/passport-examples/tree/master/example-simple-react/client/src

Comment: It stores the `forceUpdate` method of each component that has been `WithUser`ized and is currently mounted. So when the exported `update` method is called all components will get updated.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thank you! I' seeing it now. But what would i need to unsubscribe() (in componentWillUnmount) everytime I rerender?

Comment: re-rendering does not cause an unmount/mount sequence. Only when the element is removed from the DOM it is unmounted. Re-rendering just allows it to use its new props or state.

Comment: Ok @GabrielePetrioli . Thank you for clarify it. Do you know the name of this method for updating the state of an application? I'm looking for more info about it.